# How to implement AgoraIO on Asp.net

Tags: javascript, agora.io

I would like to know how to implement the CDN correctly because i follow the instructions on the Dev Center and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a little more specific with your question? Agora doesn't use CDN to pass video streams. Agora uses its proprietary SD-RTN network. Are you trying to use cloud-recording SDK?